# check for data updation in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Tables:**

1. `dbo.Patients`--> Data table
2. `dbo.ResultsSTored` --> stores already calculated results to avoid redundant calculations

   ```
    if not exists(select Top 1 PercentMatch from dbo.ResultsStored where HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
    AND ModifiedAt  > (Select MAX(ModifiedAt) FROM dbo.Patients as Pat WHERE Pat.RowID = ResultsStored.RowID ))
            begin
           /*some code that calls functions that check for percentage match in dbo.Patients*/
               end
               else
               begin
               select SearchSerial,StringSearched, RowId, PercentMatch  from dbo.ResultsStored where HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat) order by SearchSerial desc, PercentMatch desc

                end
   ```

Now, there may arise a situation when the searched results are present in dbo.ResultsStored from two days back but yesterday someone added a new row in dbo.Patients table which may have higher match percentage than what is already there in `dbo.ResultsStored` table.

In that case what dbo.ResultsStored is giving me is not the row with highest percentage.

`dbo.ResultsStored` table is basically meant to avoid unnecessary look ups in `dbo.patients` table when what we are looking for is there in `dbo.ResultsStored` table already.

But how do I handle new data added to `dbo.Patients` table to get updated and correct results.

Comment: Like I have suggested to several of your questions for the same topic, how about clearing the cache when updates happen?

Comment: I had followed exactly the same approach but the requirement is to maintain audit trails and for that purpose I have another column that i called finalSearchSerial as above which is updated at times when we have data updation. But above question is different from what I had previously asked. Earlier it was about rows being updated which were already present and in above question i ask for situations when I have results in ResultsStored table but may be new data was added to dbo.Patients table .

Comment: Well don't you think you should maybe mention your requirements in your question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `ResultsStored` is refreshed on some kind of schedule. How about having a view which only gets the records in `Patients` that aren't in `ResultsStored` and calculates the `PercentMatch` only for those few records. You could then `Union` that with your `ResultsStored` table so you get the benefit of not having to re-calculate historical data and you get to include the most recent data with minimal overhead.

Comment: Thank you. That can work. I have  /*some code */ inside of if not statement . This code is skipped when we find matching results in ResultsStored table. How do I get back to this code inside if not statement to calculate result for rest of the statements ? All above mentioned code is inside of a stored procedure.

Comment: It is hard to answer that wothout greater context, eg some representative data.The `some code` you speak of, is its purpose to update the ResultsStored table? If not then Im thinking that rather than have your sp looking at ResultsStored, have it look at a view which is the `Union` I mention above.